# Installed GIT for Mac, but cannot locate file

Tags: macos, git

I'm a new MAC user running OS X Mavricks and I am trying to get git up and running on my MAC.  I successfully downloaded the program from the website and ran it.  However I can not find it installed on my computer.  Only thing I find is the download package.  Can anyone tell me how/where I can look to find my git install, so I can finish setting it up to connect to my git repositories.

Answer (score -1):

Per the answers from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623739/locate-git-installation-folder-on-mac-os-x), you can use the command `which git` from the terminal or look in the common installation folders: `/usr/local/git`, `/usr/bin`, or `/usr/bin/git`.

Answer (score -1):

You don't indicate whether you downloaded the command-line version of git or a GUI version, but I'm going to assume the former, as the GUI version is called "GitHub" and appears where you drag it, usually Applications.  If the Terminal is not something you're comfortable with, you can use GitHub's own GUI tool, which you can download [here](https://mac.github.com/).

Another free GUI option is [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), which is by Atlassian.

Answer (score -2):

In Terminal type in `locate git`